# Regex search pattern to extract string with 2 words limit

Tags: python, regex

Looking to build some pattern using `my_string` as starting point to extract from **my_string till Inc.** i.e. Papa Johns *some_text* Inc

`my_string_1 = 'Papa Johns'`

`my_string_1 = 'Inc.'`

Need to search in any of the below sentences.

`sent_1 = The company Papa Johns Retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.`

`sent_2 = The company Papa Johns Retail Chain., Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.`

`sent_3 = The company Papa Johns Retail Chain, Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.`

`sent_4 = The company Papa Johns Retail., Chain, Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.`

`sent_5 = The company Papa Johns Retail, Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.`

I built a pattern `pattern = '''Papa Johns (.{,30})Inc.'''` and also this is working fine.

Is this possible if I do not use 30 chars condition but use 2 words limit (may be space split) to extract the required for all sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pattern:

```regex
\bPapa Johns(?: \S+){0,2} Inc\.
```

This matches `Papa Johns ... Inc.` with at most 2 words in between.

Python script:

```
inp = ["The company Papa Johns Retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.", "The company Papa Johns New Retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc."]
for i in inp:
    if re.search(r'\bPapa Johns(?: \S+){0,2} Inc\.', i):
        print("MATCH:    " + i)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH: " + i)
```

This prints:

```
MATCH:    The company Papa Johns Retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.
NO MATCH: The company Papa Johns New Retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.
```

Comment: Looks good.  Can you pl explain each pattern expression?

Comment: The regex pattern matches `Papa Johns` followed by a space and a non whitespace term, zero, one, or at most two times, followed by `Inc.`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Just to add a point - What if I want it to be matched against the text which had their first letter in UPPERCASE ? Like below-

```
MATCH:    The company Papa Johns Retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.
NO MATCH: The company Papa Johns retail Chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.
NO MATCH: The company Papa Johns retail chain Inc. sells pizza, pastas etc.
```